# Use BJT transistor as a switch without inverting the signal

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, switching

I know I can use a transistor as a switch like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhH2Ju.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Can I use only one transistor that will output the same signal (not inverted)? I want to use it to shift voltage level. The input is digital at 3.3V and should output 5V TTL levels.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This circuit tends to be used quite often: -

[image]

Comment: Very interesting. Would it be possible to put one GPIO of a board such Raspberry or BeagleBone at the input without frying the board? What I don't understand is: at the basis you have a constant voltage, the collector is pulled up. So how can you be sure that no current is moving from the 5V to the input? Eventually destroying the driving board?

Comment: Because the transistor is configured as an emitter follower and the voltage on the emitter is base voltage minus about 0.6V. If the emitter got higher it would turn off the transistor thus preventing the voltage rising much above about 3V. Think of base and emitter and what differential voltage they must be at to stat to turn the transistor on.

Comment: @Andyaka Will this work if we change 5V to 3.3V?

Comment: If you did that you wouldn’t need a level shifter.

Answer (score 21):

[Absolutely.](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/mosfet-voltage-level-converter)

[image]

This circuit takes advantages of the properties of a MOSFET to bidirectionally switch a signal between two different voltage levels.

Comment: I was interested in doing this with a bipolar PNP or NPN.

Comment: @Cornelius This answer is the better one dude because it is bidirectional whereas my circuit is not.

Comment: I know it's bidirectional. I have seen this circuit before in a schematic for an I2C level shifter. But for what I need unidirectional is enough.

Comment: @Andyaka: You're a good guy. Ignacio: useful circuit :)

Comment: @bitsmack yeah I'm all-heart muhuhahaha

Comment: If you have 5V on both sides, can you use single resistor?

Comment: If you have 5V on both sides then why do you need a level shifter?

Answer (score 9):

> The input is digital at 3.3V and should output 5V TTL levels.

For this situation you very likely do not need any conversion circuit at all.

Both 3.3 V and 5 V TTL logic switch with a threshold of about 0.8 V. Therefore no conversion circuit is needed to drive a 5 V TTL input with a 3.3 V logic signal. To be absolutely sure, check the minimum V<sub>ih</sub> of your 5 V TTL device and make sure this number is less than the minimum V<sub>oh</sub> of your 3.3 V device.

This figure, from the TI app note, "[Selecting the Right Level-Translation Solution](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/scea035a/scea035a.pdf)", shows that the specified input, output, and threshold levels are the same for 5 V and 3.3 V TTL circuits:

[image]

If your devices are actually not TTL but CMOS, you may still be able to connect them without a conversion circuit, but noise margin will be reduced because the CMOS switching threshold is V<sub>cc</sub>/2 rather than a fixed voltage level.

As you see from the chart, you cannot reliably use a 3.3 V TTL signal (or even 5 V TTL) signal to switch a 5 V CMOS input, so for either of those situations you would need a converter circuit as outlined by the other answers here.